# How to animate all sprite images?

Tags: jquery, css, sprite, css-sprites, sprite-sheet

How to do you animate all image sprite when you have a choosen image sprite does not contain one line images?

**This one example here has a one line image **

Link : [Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/)

```css
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
    
    -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
         -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
            animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png" />
<div class="hi"></div>
```

Now this example contains sprite images that is not one line. But contains 3 rows of sprite images. How do you animate this like the link the code snippet above? Do I use jquery/javascript in displaying it? Please help.

```css
img {display: block;margin: auto;}

.sample {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("https://fermmm.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/preview.jpg");
            animation: play 1s steps(4) infinite;
}
@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -299px; }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://fermmm.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/preview.jpg" />

<div style="text-align:center;">Sprite image</div>
<div class="sample"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two separate keyframe animations are created to traverse 4 frames horizontally and 3 frames vertically. When one direction animation is in play, the other one must be frozen.

Since 1s is set to go through 4 horizontal frame, so the next vertical frame would start 1s later, and therefore duration of vertical direction equals to 1s x 3 vertical frames.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.sample {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://fermmm.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/preview.jpg");
  animation: playh 1s steps(4) infinite, playv 3s steps(3) infinite;
}

@keyframes playv {
  0% { background-position-y: 0px; }
  100% { background-position-y: -301px; }
}

@keyframes playh {
  0% { background-position-x: 0px; }
  100% { background-position-x: -299px; }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://fermmm.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/preview.jpg" />

<div style="text-align:center;">Sprite image</div>
<div class="sample"></div>
```